# How do I know if I changed a setting in winetricks

Tags: 11.10, wine, winetricks

Right now with the Wine 1.3.35 I do not know if I have a setting activated or not, for example:

[image]

Here you see an image of the "Change Settings" option in winetricks but they do not appeared marked or at least stay marked after I have checked them. How do I know which settings are activated and which are not. In the past I could do this in the sound tab for example when I wanted to emulate sound, full sound, alsa, oss or pulseaudio. Since the options are now gone and only found in winetricks I check them but they do not stay activated or shown after closing winetricks.

I may be closing winetricks wrong or maybe there is another option somewhere to "save changes" but what I normally do is:

1. Open winetricks
2. Select default wineprefix
3. Select change settings
4. Activate the settings I want and press the OK button

If I go back to the change settings option they do not appear marked. Looks like nothing was done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the PPA from Wine and at least starting with Wine 1.4 I can confirm that Winetricks now saves the state of each setting. If they are installed they will show with a marked checkbox. The image below shows for example the settings I have installed:

[image]

Thanks to Christian for pointing me out a couple of minor details:

1. If the package installed needs a manual installation (Like ie6) in all the cases I have tried it never appears checked.
2. If the package has multiple installs (like allcodecs which installs several apps) and one of them fails, it does not show marked because it thinks they all failed.
3. Some packages show if you do the install using winetricks with the GUI option (`winetricks --gui`) and not when you do the install through the terminal.
4. There might be a need to delete the .wine folder, purge all related packages and even delete the ones stored in cache. Basically start from scratch. This at least cleared a couple of issues I have back then.

Comment: I'm using Wine 1.5.27 and the settings don't stick. They don't seem to have an effect either. So it might not be a question of which version you use but whether or not something else is simply broken :/

Comment: @Christian thanks for the comment. Added a couple of points to watch out for. Would like some feedback from you if you have the time.